# How do you make a file writable from vim in windows?

Tags: windows, vim

How do I make a file writable from Vim on a Windows machine? I currently manually go find the file in explorer, open it's properties and uncheck readonly. I would like to be able to do this more quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems `attrib` is the Windows shell command to modify file attributes.

See `:!attrib /?`

`:!attrib -R %`should remove the Read only property on the file. (It is working here the [RO] flag is modified in my status bar).

You will be prompted to reload the file (if you don't have `autoread` set) : don't ! and then save with :w!

(Rereading your question I am not sure that the Read only flag is your issue there because :w! should work anyway. )

Comment: Yes your right it does work. But this is more like the answer I was looking for I would prefer to turn readonly off from vim. I should work on wording stuff better.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I am missing something but `:w!` works for me.

Comment: @mb14: I agree. But in the question it is mentioned that readonly is unchecked. Which suggests to me we are talking simple file attributes here.

Comment: Yes this does work for me, maybe I should pay attention to those status messages! I am used to linux where using ! will not work.

Comment: Sorry I meant I manually have to go uncheck it, the readonly attribute is checked when I am editing it.

Comment: @Tom You can edit your question to reflect what you were really looking for, it will probably help the next guy with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `:saveas C:\Users\your_user_name\Desktop\temp.txt` and use explorer to copy it to its original location with UAC.

Comment: Sorry I meant to mention without using a temp file.